# WCF using soap 1.2 generates wsdl with soap 1.1 reference

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I am creating a WCF service which must have a soap 1.2 endpoint. The service is using the following custom binding:

```
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="httpsBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <transactionFlow />
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" >
            <secureConversationBootstrap allowInsecureTransport="true"></secureConversationBootstrap>
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

All right until here, the packages are in the right format (soap 1.2) when debugged via fiddler:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><s:Header>...
```

But investigating the WSDL generated, the binding seems to be referring the soap 1.1 schema.

```
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
```

There is no reference for http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope on the WSDL. Though it's working, I guess there is something wrong since the WSDL seems not to be describing the service correctly.

Comment: What is the binding type you are using? Is it `basichttpbinding`?

Comment: customBinding, the protocol soap 1.2 is defined within a tag textMessageEncoding on the attribute 'messageVersion'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the below changes in `web.config` (OR) `app.config` file

```
<Configuration>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <remove name="HttpSOAP"/>
            <add name="HttpSOAP12" />
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, now the namespace for soap12 is explicit:
`xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"`

though Im still confused about the line:
`<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>`

Comment: SOAP 1.1 : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
SOAP 1.2 : http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
http://wso2.com/library/articles/differentiating-between-soap-versions-looking-soap-message/

Answer (score 2):

```
<Configuration>
 <system.web>
   <webServices>
     <protocols>
        <remove name="HttpSOAP"/>
        <add name="HttpSOAP12"/>
     </protocols>
  </webServices>
</system.web>
```

websServices needs to be enclosed within the system.web section. If not the soltuion throws error " The configuration section 'webServices' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration "